# Connect to SQL Server (view)

Tags: symfony

I developed a web application running on MySQL and now I need to get some data from another database (Microsoft SQL Server).

The SQL Server administrator creates a view to give me the data I need. Now the question is:

How can I work with this data on my current Symfony2 application?. This data will be only read only data, but eventually I´ll record some of this data on MySQL.

Do I need to develop another app, in python for example, to extract that SQL Server view data and save them into MySQL table?

Comment: are you using doctrine2?

Comment: I use symfony2, so I think I´m using doctrine2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter for Doctrine that your entities refer to a view or a real table, so declare the entity of view like other entities and use it as you want for queries, relations with other entities, etw.